# What is the easiest way to make a copy of an application deployed on Azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I've currently started working on an ASP.net web application that has been deployed onto Azure. I have been asked to investigate some of the errors with this application but in order to do this I first have been instructed to create a local or developer copy so that any changes I make can be reviewed before they are implemented onto the live version.

The setup on Azure appears to be three virtual machines that run web scrapers and some services, a web server, and a database server. I have access to the source files from team foundation server but I have no idea how it has all been deployed. Unfortunately the developers who created this application are no longer employed by the company so I am unable to ask them for guidance.

As I have all the source code should it be possible to just run the application on my machine provided I can somehow either copy the database or directly access it? Alternatively is there any simple way to make a direct clone of the entire project for me to work on?

I'm a total novice when it comes to Azure so I've never had to do anything like this previously. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can loggin into the VM and get the application which I suppose, is hosting on IIS. But the app is compiled, so you'll need to decompile it.

It's better to use the source code you received. Then, to publish it again, just publish to a local folder and copy to IIS again.

Comment: Thanks @Thiago, I'll give that a try tomorrow.